# Put value null if none of checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html

```
    get_genre_value=this.value; //setting value of current check box to get_genre_value.
```

Here i had globally declared `var get_genre_value;` which is necessary for my project and I am taking the value from `get_genre_value` on button click. Selecting checkbox value and getting it was easy but how am I able to set the value to null for get_genre_value if no check box is selected this got me thinking hard, as the get_genre_value will use its value stored globbaly if I try to click the button second time without selecting any checkbox , any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please make this an actual [mcve] and while doing that fix the indentation and the syntax error.

Comment: have you tried by declaring and using 2 different variables ?

Comment: Do you use checkboxes because it is be possible to select no value? Because you could use radio buttons instead of it, if it is not possible to select no value

Comment: @Mohit I am trying to set value to null if none of the check box is selected would declaring 2 variable for it be useful?

Comment: @Apollo79 I used like 17 checkboxes for my project, I just want to know how can I get null value if none of checkbox were checked

Comment: Removing everything but one line without any meaning is still not a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to do it:
You set `get_genre_value` to `null` in the beginning.
For each checkbox you add an EventListener. In the callback you check, if the checkbox is checked:

- It is: You uncheck the checkbox that was checked before (it is perhaps `null` if no checkbox was checked before) and set get_genre_value to the value of the checkbox
- It is not: You set get_genre_value to `null` again

```js
let get_genre_value = null;

const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=select]");

checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const checkedbefore = document.querySelector(`input[name=select][value=\"${get_genre_value}\"]`);
      
      if (checkedbefore !== null)
        checkedbefore.checked = false;

      get_genre_value = event.target.value;
    } else {
      get_genre_value = null;
    }
    
    console.log(get_genre_value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="select" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="select" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="select" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="select" value="4">
```

Comment: Thanks i got some rough ideas to implement it on my code

Comment: Another idea: Store the currently checked checkbox in a variable too, so you can just do `currentlyCheckedCheckbox.checked = false` and the assign the other checkbox to it. So you don't have to search the DOM with `document.querySelector all the time`